# Etherscan Unable to locate Transaction entry

Tags: parity, pending-transactions, ropsten

I'm using the Ropsten network with Parity and when I send a transaction from an account to another account I get the good transaction hash. When I'm trying to call `getTransaction(transaction_hash)` I can see my transaction but I can't see it on [etherscan](https://testnet.etherscan.io). When I search my transaction with my hash I got this message `Unable to locate Transaction entry`. I don't understand why because I can see the pending transaction with the `getTransaction()`

So I have to know when my transaction is published on the blockchain. But my transaction is stuck in pending status since 1 month. I don't understand why...

Do you have an idea why all my transactions are stuck up ?